# TCP Client can't read data from server

Tags: java, android, tcp, network-programming

So I have a TCP client running on an Androidt tablet, and I have a c++ server running on a PC.

I send data from my tablet to the PC and the PC can read them just fine, but when the PC tries to send back a message to the tablet, the tablet just receives nothing. It gets stuck in the `readLine()` call trying to read something.

So here is the java methods sending and then waiting for a response

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
{   
    String msg = "";
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    BufferedReader msgFromServer = null;
    try 
    {
        // Socket used for I/O with the server
        socket = new Socket("192.168.20.100", 48501);

        // Writing to the server
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

        // Reading from the server
        msgFromServer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ) );
        DataInputStream iStrReader = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );

        // Initial comm
        outToServer.writeBytes( "MainCamConnect" );

        msg = msgFromServer.readLine(); // Get stuck here
        Log.d( "NETWORK", msg );

        socket.close();

    } 
    catch( UnknownHostException e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch( IOException e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return( null );
}
```

and the message I send from the PC is this : "StartDelayTest\n"

I know the server can send message just fine because I tested it with a simple c++ TCP client and it worked just fine, but when I run it on the tablet, the tablet can't get anything

EDIT:

OS : Windows 7 64 bits Professional edition

EDIT 2:

I've run wireshark on my computer and I can confirm that the packets are being sent to the right address IP, so the problem is indeed in the receiving end (the android app)

Comment: Windows 7 64 bits Professional edition

Comment: You might want to try reading the raw bytes from the socket inputStream, and/or reading in such a way that doesn't wait until it receives `'\n'`, as the behavior you mention sounds like an encoding issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case I tried with an other computer (not java) and I got the same results, so I'm guessing it's something with the LAN and not android. However, when I tried connecting to the server through my WAN IP address, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing them. writeBytes() just writes those bytes. Lines end with a newline. readLine() will block until it receives one.

Answer (score -1):

I would try using public `int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` instead so your code would be something like:

```
char[] buffer = new char[256];
int count = read(buffer, 0, 256);
```

readline for network buffers isn't used very often in typical client server apps.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't change the result

Comment: Try changing the buffer to one character. See if that changes anything.